# How do I prevent my Bluetooth headphones from dropping audio on OS X?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a pair of Beats Studio Wireless headphones. They work great most of the time. However, sometimes, they will start to skip and drop in and out (as if I were plugging and unplugging an audio cable). The speed of the audio will increase after it skips to "catch up".

I've seen various suggestions about changing some Bluetooth defaults to increase audio quality, but that's not what I need. I don't know much about Bluetooth, but is there a way for me to basically prioritize the audio device or increase some buffer limit so it doesn't skip so much?

I have a wireless Apple Keyboard and Magic Mouse, and I work in an office environment, so there are dozens of other Bluetooth devices around me. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

(As a side note, I notice Bluetooth headphones will sometimes do the same thing when paired with my iPhone, with no other Bluetooth devices nearby.)